# What does Arnold mean here by $x=\alpha 1 + \beta A$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm reading Arnold's "Geometry and dynamics of Galois fields" (the russian version is [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/10b46d3fc882199554c40dc4cc075305/rm793.pdf)), he mentions --

> Ch1. Construction of the table of a field
>
> **Definition**. By a *Galois field* we mean a field with finitely many
>   elements. The simplest example is given by the residue class field $Z_p
>  = Z/(pZ)$ modulo a prime $p$. This field consists of $p$ elements.
>
> The following theorem about such fields is classical.
>
> **Theorem**. The number of elements in an arbitrary Galois field is equal
>   to $p^a$, where $p$ is a prime and $a$ is a positive integer. A field
>   with this number of elements exists (for any number of the form $p^a$)
>   and is unique (up to isomorphism of fields, of course).
>
> To represent the operations of addition and multiplication in a field,
>   we enumerate its elements as follows. The field has a zero element 0
>   (which is uniquely determined by the condition that $0 + x = x$ for
>   any element $x$), and the other elements form a group (the
>   multiplicative group $F\backslash 0$ of the field $F$) with respect to the
>   multiplication, that is, they have inverse elements $x^{−1}$ for which
>   $xx^{−1} = 1$ (where the element 1 is uniquely determined by the
>   condition that $y1 = y$ for any element $y$).
>
> It turns out that the multiplicative group of a field is always cyclic
>   (of order $p^\alpha − 1$ for a field with $p^\alpha$ elements), that
>   is, every element of this group can be expressed in terms of one of
>   these elements, say, $A$ (a ‘multiplicative generator’), in the form
>   $$A,A^2, A^3, \dots, A^{p^\alpha−1} = 1.$$
>
> The generator $A$ can be chosen in different ways. Namely, any $B =
> A^k$ with $k$ prime to $p^\alpha − 1$ can be taken as the generator.
>
> Thus, the number of multiplicative generators is equal to the value of
>   the Euler function, $\varphi(p^\alpha − 1)$.
>
> **Example**. For a field with $p^\alpha = 49$ elements the number of
>   generators is equal to $\varphi(48) = 16$, namely, the generators are
>   the elements $A^k$ with $$k = 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31,
>  35, 37, 41, 43, 47.$$
>
> The multiplicative generators form a multiplicative subgroup (in the
>   residue class ring modulo pa − 1). For instance, if $p^\alpha = 49$,
>   then $$5 ·5 = 25, 7 ·7 = 1, 5 · 11 = 7.$$
>
> With respect to addition, a field of $p^a$ elements is a $p$-vector
>   space (the commutative group $(\mathbb Z_p)^a$), and thus the $p^a$
>   elements of this field can be inscribed into cells of a ‘finite torus’
>   of dimension $a$, $$x = x_1e_1 + \cdots + x_ae_a$$, where 
>   $(e_1, \cdots, e_a)$ are the additive generators and 
>   the coefficients $x_j$
>   are residues modulo $p$.
>
> **Example**. A field of 49 elements consists of the combinations of the
>   form $$x = \alpha_1+ \beta A$$, where $1$ is the ‘identity’ element of
>   the field and $A$ is the multiplicative generator discussed above (in
>   the general case one can take the elements 
>   $\{A,A^2, \cdots, A^{a−1}, A^a=1\}$ 
>   as the additive generators).
>
> For a field of $p^2$ elements we conclude that (1)
>   $$A^2 = \alpha 1 +\beta A  $$ 
>   with some coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in 
>   $\mathbb Z_p$.

I'm confused here. Taking $49$ as example, $p=7, a=2$, what is a $p$-vector space? Taking $A=5$, how could (1) works?

$$A^2 = 25 = \alpha 1 + \beta 5$$

what are the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ here? Seems $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in $\mathbb Z_5$ so could only take values from $\{0, 1,2,3,4\}$, $\alpha 1 + \beta 5$ won't makes 25?

Comment: Short for vector spaces over a field of $p$ elements.

Comment: @Randall i also assumed so. but how to make $25 = \alpha 1 + \beta 5$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: I don't know what $>$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: Do you know how to build finite fields from quotients by irreducible polynomials?  This is an incredibly important story, and essentially what he is doing.

Comment: @Randall no i don't. could you pls give me a short introduction on that? some link or some chapter of a book?

Comment: I spend about a *month* on all the machinery when I teach this.  Any good intro algebra book will do this.  You can try this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395028/how-to-deal-with-polynomial-quotient-rings

Comment: See example 5.24 here:  http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/OldWebPages/Math331Spring2003/Chapter5.pdf

Comment: @Randall thank you so much , let me digest.

Comment: @Randall thank you so much. now i see where i was lost. I'm reading "Abstract Algebrqa" by Finston and Morandi, a newer version of the script, e.g. its Example 5.27 is the example 5.24 in the notes. A even simpler one is Example 5.26, which is isomorphic to Example 3.30 of $F=\{0,1,a,b\}$, where here $p^a=2$. My mistake was, I thought $F_4$ is just just $Z_4$, $a$ is just $2$ and $b$ is $3$. but actually it is not! Thanks again, I see where i'm lacking in foundation, and will pick those up.

Comment: Correct.  If $F$ is a field of order $p^d$ where $d>1$, $F$ will **never** be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^d}$.  That's because the latter has zero divisors, so is not a field to begin with.

Comment: @Randall side topic, do you think it’s is typo that in Example 5.26 the second table lists (1+x+I) * (1+x+I) = 1+x+I ? It seems shall be x+I.

Comment: I don't know how you're representing your field, so I can't answer.  Though, it doesn't matter.  In any field, $e^2=e$ implies either $e=0$ or $e=1$.  So, in your case, it is not possible.